# error parsing http.post response in angular

Tags: angular-httpclient

I call to webAPI from my Angular Project like this

```
this.dataService.postCabeceraHistoricos(cabeceraHistorico)
.subscribe(
  data=>{
    ultimoCodeCabeceraHistorico=data;
  }
  ,err=>console.log(err)
  ,()=>{
    this.guardarHistoricoDetalleHoras(ultimoCodeCabeceraHistorico);
  }
);
```

In dataService I have this

```
postCabeceraHistoricos(data:CabeceraHistorico):Observable<string>{
const config = { headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json') };

return this.http.post<string>(`${this.urlProyecto}/planning/PostCabeceraHistorico`,data,config)
  .pipe(
    catchError(this.handleError)
  )
```

}

I send the object to insert but I need in response the code of the inserted register

Then I debug webAPI and I see that I get the correct value I need, that is, the code of the actual register inserted

[image: response]

But in Angular I always get this error

[image: error]

Any idea, please?

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution

```
postCabeceraHistoricos(data:CabeceraHistorico):Observable<string>{
const headers = new HttpHeaders({
  'content-type' : 'application/json',
  'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*'
});

return this.http.post(`${this.urlProyecto}/planning/PostCabeceraHistorico`,data, {headers, responseType:'text'})
  .pipe(
    catchError(this.handleError)
  )
```

}

the responseType